# Setting count() cutoff in Altair?

Tags: python, altair

Here is a simple plot using altair:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a',2],['a',3],['b',4],['b',5],['b',4],['c',8]], columns=['Letters', 'Numbers'])
```

I'm plotting the `count()` for each letter: so `a:2`, `b:3`, and `c:1`.

```
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
   alt.X('Letters:N', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(op='count', order='descending')),
   alt.Y('count():Q'))
```

[image]

How can I filter the data such that, for example, `count()` must be >= 2, so only `a` and `b` are plotted? I know how to do this with `pandas`, but would like to do it all in one step with `altair`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using an aggregate transform, followed by a filter transform:

```
alt.Chart(df).transform_aggregate(
    count='count()',
    groupby=['Letters']
).transform_filter(
    'datum.count >= 2'
).mark_bar().encode(
   alt.X('Letters:N', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(op='count', order='descending')),
   alt.Y('count:Q')
)
```

[image]